# Using UIPicker to create desired number of rows in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a view with my `UIPicker` that will push to my `UITableViewController` when my start button is pressed.

I want to create a certain number of rows per section in my `UITableViewController` from my `UIPicker`.

Here is the relevant code. I'm not getting errors. My `UITableViewController` just doesn't have any rows in its sections. Any advice or examples on how I could get this to work would be great. Or if someone knows a better way of going about this that would be equally appreciated.

from PushView.m

```
    @interface WorkoutPushViewController ()
{
NSArray *_PickerData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//picker
_PickerData = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10"];
self.setsPicker.dataSource = self;
self.setsPicker.delegate = self;
}
```

from TableView.h

```
    @interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (nonatomic, retain) PushViewController *pushReference;
    @end
```

from TableView.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return ([self.pushReference.setsPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]+1);
// +1 because index 0 is 1 row. 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you just need to send picker value as a number or int value and that will be need to set as a Tableview numberOfRowInSection. So that will be create that number of row in tableview.

Comment: @NitinGohel I've tried to do that but I'm not doing it correctly and getting this warning:  Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'long'). I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nitin Gohel said: 
In your TableView.h

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfRows;
@end
```

And in your TableView.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return self.numberOfRows;
}
```

Don't forget to assign the value of number of rows when your start button is tapped.

Comment: I am able to assign the value of number of rows when I tap the start button. But I think when the views change the selected row goes back to 0.

Comment: Do you need to keep the selected row ?if you have the number of rows you have enough to build your table view. am I right? How do you show your picker ? It's always visible?

Comment: I agree. I thought that having the number of rows would be enough. To answer your question my picker and tableview are in different views, so my picker is not always visible. In my start button method the numberOfRows was correct. But in my output in my tableViewController's numberOfRowsInSection Method is wrong. When I return self.pushReference.numberOfRows i always get 0. Thanks in advance.

Comment: number of rows should be a property of your tableview and not of workout pushviewcontroller. Btw have you checked if your self.pushReference is not null ?

Comment: You were right. Thanks for being patient. My brain finally started working and realized that in my StartButton method I needed to set the numberOfRows after I initialized the TableViewController but before I navigated there. thanks again.